# Printing an AVL Tree by level in Java

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I am attempting to take an AVL tree and display it, level by level, but I'm failing somehow and don't know where. Attached is an image showing my current output. What I actually should be getting is a full binary tree, so obviously something is going wrong. In the attached image, there is a photo of my "byLevel" print function, so you can see how I'm attempting to print them, and I will attach my insert function, as those are the only two functions that matter for this part. I'd appreciate any help, I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, as this is a commonly used algorithm.

```
private Node insert(Node newNode, String newWord){
    if(newNode == null){
        newNode = new Node(newWord);
    }
    else if (newWord.compareToIgnoreCase(newNode.getReservedWord()) < 0){
        newNode.setlChild(insert(newNode.getlChild(), newWord));

        if(depth(newNode.getlChild()) - depth(newNode.getrChild()) == 2){
            if(newWord.compareToIgnoreCase(newNode.getlChild().getReservedWord()) < 0){
                newNode = rotateWithLeftChild(newNode);
            }
            else{
                newNode = doubleWithLeftChild(newNode);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (newWord.compareToIgnoreCase(newNode.getReservedWord()) > 0){
        newNode.setrChild(insert(newNode.getrChild(), newWord));

        if(depth(newNode.getrChild()) - depth(newNode.getlChild()) == 2){
            if(newWord.compareToIgnoreCase(newNode.getrChild().getReservedWord()) > 0){
                newNode = rotateWithRightChild(newNode);
            }
            else{
                newNode = doubleWithRightChild(newNode);
            }
        }
    }
    else;

    newNode.setDepth(max(depth(newNode.getlChild()), depth(newNode.getrChild()) + 1));
    /*if(!this.getAllNodes().contains(newNode)){
        this.getAllNodes().add(newNode);
    }*/
    return newNode;
}

private Node rotateWithLeftChild(Node nodeToRotate){
    Node newNode = nodeToRotate.getlChild();
    nodeToRotate.setlChild(newNode.getrChild());
    newNode.setrChild(nodeToRotate);
    nodeToRotate.setDepth(max(depth(nodeToRotate.getlChild()), depth(nodeToRotate.getrChild()) + 1));
    newNode.setDepth(max(depth(newNode.getlChild()), nodeToRotate.getDepth() + 1));
    return newNode;
}

private Node rotateWithRightChild(Node nodeToRotate){
    Node newNode = nodeToRotate.getrChild();
    nodeToRotate.setrChild(newNode.getlChild());
    newNode.setlChild(nodeToRotate);
    nodeToRotate.setDepth(max(depth(nodeToRotate.getlChild()), depth(nodeToRotate.getrChild()) + 1));
    newNode.setDepth(max(depth(newNode.getrChild()), nodeToRotate.getDepth() + 1));
    return newNode;
}

private Node doubleWithLeftChild(Node nodeToRotate){
    nodeToRotate.setlChild(rotateWithRightChild(nodeToRotate.getlChild()));
    return rotateWithLeftChild(nodeToRotate);
}

private Node doubleWithRightChild(Node nodeToRotate){
    nodeToRotate.setrChild(rotateWithLeftChild(nodeToRotate.getrChild()));
    return rotateWithRightChild(nodeToRotate);
}
```

[TestOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUZ7Z.png)

Comment: Currently I'm unable to understand what you exactly are doing, since lot of code is missing, and it is not possible to reproduce it. What I can suggest is just a "best practice" widely used in cases like this: prepare a JUnit to test all 4 relevant AVL rotation cases and check if they work correctly. In this way you can also rephrase your question explaining what is not working, and when insert does not maintain tree balanced, so you can understand what was wrong and where you (or we) can investigate. PS: add also depth of node in your visit: I think that there is something wrong there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again, fixed my own problem, and yes, the code provided was enough. The problem was simply that I was miscalculating my depth by adding +1 to the second of the max function, instead of adding it after the max function. I think the question was well-stated enough on it's own since AVL trees are common coding. Thanks.